# How to allow EACCESS for :8080 in order to run webpack dev server?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, webpack-dev-server

As I am learning to manually configure Webpack, I am encountering this error (EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:8080) when running the start script.
The result is:

```
× ｢wds｣:  Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 127.0.0.1:8080
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1292:21)
    at listenInCluster (net.js:1357:12)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.doListen [as callback] (net.js:1496:7)
    at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:69:10) {
  code: 'EACCES',
  errno: 'EACCES',
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 8080
}
i ｢wdm｣: asset bundle.js 362 KiB [emitted] (name: main)
runtime modules 430 bytes 3 modules
cacheable modules 333 KiB
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/ 20.9 KiB 10 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/html-entities/lib/*.js 61 KiB 5 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/url/ 37.4 KiB 3 modules
  modules by path ./node_modules/querystring/*.js 4.51 KiB
    ./node_modules/querystring/index.js 127 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/querystring/decode.js 2.34 KiB [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/querystring/encode.js 2.04 KiB [built] [code generated]
  modules by path ./node_modules/webpack/hot/*.js 1.42 KiB
    ./node_modules/webpack/hot/emitter.js 75 bytes [built] [code generated]
    ./node_modules/webpack/hot/log.js 1.34 KiB [built] [code generated]
./node_modules/webpack/hot/ sync nonrecursive ^\.\/log$ 170 bytes [built] [code generated]
webpack 5.11.0 compiled successfully in 470 ms
i ｢wdm｣: Compiled successfully.
```

While it says it compiled successfully, it actually didn't bundle anything.
This is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "webpack_test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack serve --config ./webpack.config.js --mode development",
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.11.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0"
  }
}
```

and this one is my webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
  },
};
```

How do I allow this EACCES on windows 10?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OK I think I found the solution. I think some other process is running on 8080 so I added port: 3000 to the devServer property in the webpack.config.js and it works now. I leave this here in case someone will face the same issue